# How to auto-arrange pattern in a preg_match or preg_replace function?

Tags: php, regex

I have this variable I fetched from database:

$var = ':D 3:D =)';

I need to use this variable to replace it with something else using preg functions.

Problem is special characters like ":","=" need to be backslashed "\:","\=" in order to work in pattern section of preg functions. How can I filter all special characters of a variable to have a backslash "\" as a prefix?

Using preg is necessary here because I need to match a word as a whole or the word '3:D' will be replaced with '3[THE REPLACE CODE FOR ':D']'.

Comment: Huh, you don't need to escape `:` or `=` in regex. You must escape `)` however. And you could probably use a negative lookbehind to make sure `:` in `3:D` doesn't get replaced like `:D`.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`preg_quote`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php) to quote regular expression characters in a string, i.e. prevent them from being interpreted as special characters in regex.